# Calculate percentages by 2 groups for figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, summarize

I am trying to calculate some percentages that I can then plot, and am running into trouble. Visually, my goal is to get something like the attached plot below (which my current code produces), except with percentages broken down by whether or not they graduated.

To be more clear, in my example data below, I'd want to plot something that would tell me: "Within employment category 0/1/2, what percent of white individuals graduated vs. did not graduate". And then have that for each of the race, gender, and yr (year) variables.

Here is my initial code. The issue, I think, is in my code chunk where I am trying to calculate percentages. My current code is calculating those for the whole group, instead of breaking each down by grad vs. not.

```
Code: 
test2 <- test %>% 
  mutate(
    genderf = factor(2-gender),
    racef = factor(race),
    yrf = factor(yr),
    gradf = factor(grad)) %>% 
  select(genderf, racef, yrf, gradf, employ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(!employ, names_to = "group", values_to = "levels")

test3 <- test2 %>% 
  group_by(group, levels) %>% 
  mutate(group_n  = n()) %>% 
  group_by(group, levels, employ) %>% 
  summarize(percent = round(100*n()/group_n[1], 1))

test3 <- test3 %>% 
  mutate(var = case_when(group == "genderf" & levels == 1 ~ "female",
                         group == "genderf" & levels == 2 ~ "male",
                         group == "racef" & levels == 1 ~ "white",
                         group == "racef" & levels == 2 ~ "black",
                         group == "racef" & levels == 3 ~ "hispanic",
                         group == "racef" & levels == 4 ~ "otherrace",
                         group == "yrf" & levels == 11 ~ "class '11",
                         group == "yrf" & levels == 15 ~ "class '15")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(var))

ggplot(test3, aes(x = percent, y = var, fill = group)) +
  geom_col(orientation = "y", width = .9) +
  facet_grid(group ~ employ,
               scales = "free", space = "free_y") +
  labs(title = "Demographic breakdown of 'Score'",
         y = "",
         x = "Percent") +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

```
test <- structure(list(gender = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0), race = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 
3, 0, 1, 1, 0), yr = c(11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 
11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 
11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 
11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 11, 15, 
11), grad = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0), employ = c(1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 
2)), row.names = c(NA, -59L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    gender = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), race = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), yr = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), grad = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), employ = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x000001283e363ab0>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? I simplified things quite a bit.

```r
library(tidyverse)

test |>
  mutate(gender = c("female", "male")[gender + 1],
         race = c("white","black", "hispanic", "otherrace")[race + 1],
         yr = glue::glue("class_{yr}")) |>
  pivot_longer(-c(grad, employ), names_to = "group") |>
  group_by(employ, group, value)|>
  summarise(percent = sum(grad)/n() * 100, .groups = "drop") |>
  ggplot(aes(x = percent, y = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_col(orientation = "y", width = .9) +
  facet_grid(group ~ employ,
               scales = "free", space = "free_y") +
  labs(title = "Demographic breakdown of 'Score'",
         y = "",
         x = "Percent") +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: This is close but with each demographic characteristic broken down by grad vs. not, within each employment category. @Ludwig 2nd image shows exactly what I was looking for. I do appreciate this simplification of the code!

Comment: I see what the second image shows. This plot shows the same exact thing. It shows the percent grad by every category. Because grad is a binary variable, showing the percent no grad is redundant and clutters the plot.

Comment: Oh I see now, sorry for not recognizing at first--I should have looked more closely. This is great and I actually do agree with the clutter point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for. I've made some minor changes to the code:

- I named the factors in the beginning
- I don't know if it was intended by you, but your race factor had levels 0 - 3. But you named factor level 4 "otherrace". I assumed that you wanted to set level 0 to "otherrace", if not I'm sure you know how to change it.
- In your lists you had no information about whether they graduated or not. I added the column and assumed that level 0 stands for "not graduated". If that's wrong, go ahead and change it. :)

Here is the code:

```
test2 <-
    test %>% transmute(
            gender = factor(case_when(gender == 0 ~ "male",
                                      TRUE ~ "female")),
            race = factor(
                    case_when(
                            race == 1 ~ "white",
                            race == 2 ~ "black",
                            race == 3 ~ "hispanic",
                            TRUE ~ "otherrace"
                    )
            ),
            yr = factor(case_when(yr == 11 ~ "class '11",
                                  TRUE ~ "class '15")),
            grad = factor(case_when(grad == 0 ~ "no",
                                    TRUE ~ "yes")),
            employ = factor(employ)
    ) %>% 
    pivot_longer(1:3, 
                 names_to = "group",
                 values_to = "levels")

test3 <- test2 %>% group_by(
        group,levels,employ, grad) %>% 
        summarize(n = n()) %>% 
        mutate(percent = n/sum(n)*100) %>% 
        select(-n)
```

Now there are multiple options how to plot the results. Only graduated %:

```
test3 %>%
        filter(grad == "yes") %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = percent, y = levels, fill = group))  +
        geom_col(orientation = "y",
                 width = .9,
                 position = "dodge2") +
        facet_grid(group ~ employ,
                   scales = "free", space = "free_y") +
        labs(title = "Demographic breakdown of 'Score'",
             y = "",
             x = "Percent") +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[graduated %](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQNCq.png)

Fill bars by graduation status:

```
test3 %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = percent, y = levels, fill = grad))  +
        geom_col(orientation = "y",
                 width = .9,
                 position = "dodge2") +
        facet_grid(group ~ employ,
                   scales = "free", space = "free_y") +
        labs(title = "Demographic breakdown of 'Score'",
             y = "",
             x = "Percent") +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[graduation status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ3ig.png)

Fill bars by group and label graduation status:

```
ggplot(test3, aes(x = percent, y = levels, fill = group))  +
        geom_col(orientation = "y",
                 width = .9,
                 position = "dodge2") +
        facet_grid(group ~ employ,
                   scales = "free", space = "free_y") +
        labs(title = "Demographic breakdown of 'Score'",
             y = "",
             x = "Percent") +
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        geom_text(aes(label = grad), position = position_dodge2(0.9))
```

[label graduation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDPm2.png)

Comment: This is fantastic and exactly what I was trying to do, thank you!